# Make taskbar and title bar black when window is maximized (like in Vista)

Tags: windows-7, windows, taskbar, user-interface

Is there a way to make the taskbar and application title bar go blank when a window is maximized, like it was in Vista?

I find it very distracting to see what's behind the maximized window (there is a reason why I maximized it). I think the decision to have only transparent window elements all the time was a stupid one, but they could have added it as an option at least. But they haven't, so I need now to draw two black bands over my wallpapers and make the chrome as dark as possible.

Comment: You should probably specify that you're using Windows 7. We can only guess from the tags.

Comment: that's what tags are for, no?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I haven't tested it (yet) but [this theme](http://thepanda-x.deviantart.com/art/Windows-7-Aero-Max-Opacity-109057049) should be pretty close to what you want.

> Requested. Just adds the old function
>   to make the window opaque when
>   maximized.

As it's a custom theme, you need a patched UXTheme to install it. You can use [UxStyle](http://uxstyle.com/) to patch it.

Comment: It works, but not the way it was in Vista. The title bar goes black, but still remains a bit transparent... and the taskbar remains 100% transparent :(